# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't display debug info for local variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't display debug info for local variables. I have no problem seeing my class variables though. Is there some setting that I'm missing?

This is a "debug" build.

I tried going to Project Properties -> C++ -> Optimizations and disable all optimizations.

Comment: Did you actually *change* the optimization setting?  Then it isn't the debug build.

Comment: No. I didn't actually change the settings. I just went there to verify that optimizations were turned off.

Comment: Give more info. Does this happen on a little toy project too or is this specific to the project you are working on now?  When did this stop working?  What are the compiler and linker command lines?

Comment: This is for a specific project. I haven't tried reproing it with a top project, but I imagine that it will work. How do I get the compiler and linker command lines? '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can help. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2452649

This is the main entry
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/6133b9d0-81c6-4e30-bfe5-5b3d6e104300

Comment: I upgraded VS2010 to SP1 which *should* have the hotfix according to that link. But, it still didn't fix it.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Which Visual studio 2010 edition are you using.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't very useful. Please bring the content here.

Answer (score 2):

check to make sure you're project is setup to export debug symbols. These should be .pdb files. They contain debug information for your code. I believe the setting is under project->Linker->generate debug info.

Comment: Yeah. That's setup so debug info is enabled. Also, I do see the pdb file being generated.

Comment: hmm.. the only thing else I can think of is looking at Caglar Gonul's answer. It appears to be a somewhat well known issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have any problem regarding this issue...

1. download the patch from here
   http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2452649/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5350
2. Restart computer
3. rebuild your project

and most probably everything will be good then....

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing it with within a switch-case statement just add a conditioned empty command like

```
if(true)
;
```

for testing purposes. It seems that some older versions of Visual Studio suffered from a bug where a missing conditioning of any kind (while, if...) in one case rendered Locals during debugging in following cases invisible.

Comment: the bug description and the workaround provided are clear, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Express (like I was) this is fixed by getting Service Pack 1, which you can get by running Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Always include just the compatible debug libraries:

I came here because Visual Studio 2010 didn't display debug info for some local variables within the opencv 2.4.2 library. In `Mat _InputArray::getMat(int i) const` I got to see several variables but k and vv were missing. (and I got an exception in `cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd` when getMat would (wrongly) return only empty matrices.)
Anyway, the problem was: I had included (as library, in the PATH for the dlls and as `#pragma comment`) both the debug and the release libraries. This seemed to have caused the problem. Everything worked well after included just the debug libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem in VS2015 by enabling Options > Debugging > General > Use Native Compatibility Mode.

[MSDN says that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) "when this option is selected, the debugger uses the Visual Studio 2010 native debugger instead of the new native debugger." We build with Intel C++ 12.1, which is based on VC10, so that makes sense!